# Returning Enum in async Task<Enum> and getting value

Tags: c#, reflection, enums, async-await, task

I was looking to return an enum depending on the outcome of my asynchronous method.

```
public enum ReponseType
{
    Success,
    Error
}
```

Here is the method that returns the response type:

```
    public async Task<ReponseType> MethodThatDoesStuff()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //Doing stuff here

            return ResponseType.Success;

        });
        return ReponseType.Error;
    }
```

when I call this method I can't get access to what the value is:

```
var resp = await _writer.MethodThatDoesStuff();
```

Even if I use:

```
ResponseType resp = await _writer.MethodThatDoesStuff();
```

I still can't get the enum value.

resp.[intellisense] only give me GetType(), GetTypeCode(), CompareTo() etc...

Is it not ok/efficient to return an enum like this if I only want to know if its a success or error?

What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: @ScottChamberlain The question isn't saying that the result is always an error, the question is saying the result can't be used at all.

Comment: This question is not complete. provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: what are you expecting to see in IntelliSense?
you are returning an enum, go compare it to another:
    if (ResponseType.Success == resp)
        //success
    else
        //error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning an enum is perfectly fine. However, your value will always be Error in this case because you are not returning the value from your Run. You should be doing the following:

```
public Task<ReponseType> MethodThatDoesStuff()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //Doing stuff here

        return ReponseType.Success;
    });
}
```

Using this you should be able to call the method as such

```
ResponseType response = await MethodThatDoesStuff();
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Yeah just tested the response and it contains the value. Wasn't available through IntelliSense thought which is what though me. Thanks for your help.